# Does attorney client privilege apply to free consultations?

Tags: united-states, attorney-client-privilege

Let's say you visit an attorney, and get half an hour or an hour of free consultation. And then decide not to use them.

Is the content of that free consultation covered by attorney client privilege? Or do you need to pay at least a nominal amount, say $1, for the privilege to hold?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The privilege is independent of the contract, otherwise a lawyer that worked *pro-bono* wouldn't grant it either.